# insert in mysql if select statement is true

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query :

```
select count(id) as tot from user where sponsor_id=10006 and exp > now();
```

The above query returns 1 as tot.

If the above query returns more than 1, it should insert a record in a table.

Comment: Can you show us sample data?

Comment: query selects and count id from table if sponsor_id ='10006' and there is a date field name exp...

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like:

```
insert into log
select 'there are more than one IDs'
from dual -- this is just a dummy table in mysql
where 1 <> (select count(id) as tot 
              from user 
             where sponsor_id=10006
               and exp > now()
           )
```

You can check [this demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c62a/1) (without the exp>now() part).